# Java: How to fetch a list of all files within folders with numeric names greater than a given integer?

Tags: java

There is a directory which has many folders with all numeric names. How to fetch a list of all files within `only those folders (as in complete path) whose numeric name is greater than a given integer` in java?

For example: Lets say directory `.../home/user` has following files and folders where each folder has multiple files within:

`.../home/user/xyz.txt`

`.../home/user/suv.txt`

`.../home/user/19620918/abc.txt`

`.../home/user/19620919/abc.txt, def.txt`

`.../home/user/19620920/abc.txt`

If integer variable `x = 19620918`, then I want a list containing

```
[.../home/user/19620919/abc.txt,

.../home/user/19620919/def.txt,

.../home/user/19620920/abc.txt]
```

How to achieve this in simplest possible way in java?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Generally you're most likely to get quality answers on SO if you show what you've tried and what's not working. That helps focus the question.

Comment: You may want to check out `FileFilter` and `FileNameFilter` in the Java API.

Comment: `stridecolossus`, `Don Branson` I am a new person in java so not able to hit on correct way for it. Would appreciate if get some help.

Comment: @Prachi Have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Have a think how you would tackle this problem, do some research or look at some tutorials and try to get something working.  You will get plenty of help when you post some code.

Comment: @Prachi Before filtering I would suggest if you haven't already done so is to simply focus on walking a directory.  There are classes that facilitate that.  But part of the process of writing code is looking over the API in key areas like File IO, etc and looking to see if anything might be helpful.  Everyone does it and it's part of the process and is essential.  And the side benefit is you will find other methods and classes that will ultimately be of use.  The more you do it, the easier it becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your folder as a File and list the files, then filter the stream with the files whose name is greater than the input number, I used a trycatch block to avoid possible errors with the files whose name is not an integer, finally, I take every of those folders, and list their files, transform that into a stream and use flatmap to collect everything in a single list.

```
Arrays.stream(new File(".../home/user").listFiles())
.filter(f -> {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(f.getName()) > 19620918;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
})
.flatMap(f -> Arrays.stream(f.listFiles()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The resulting list is a list with the files that match the condition.